# Postgres/Docker : Can't connect to localhost:5432

Tags: postgresql, docker

I am running a postgres image using a docker-compose.yml file (not in detached mode). I have created two users and two databases there. In my bash terminal I logged into both users and when I typed \conninfo it said that

```
You are connected to database "db1" as user "user1" on host "localhost" (address "127.0.0.1") at port "5432".
```

and "db2" and "user2" for the other one.

When I typed the command "sudo netstat -plunt | grep postgres" it returned the following

```
tcp   0     0 127.0.0.1:5433          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      953/postgres
```

I have a few questions.

1\ Why does it say port 5432 in the first one and 5433 in the second??

2\ When I type localhost:5432 in the url I don't see any page. It says

```
This page isn’t working
localhost didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

Why can't I see anything in the web page at the above address??

3\ In my vscode terminal I am also getting these two error messages

```
2021-12-25 22:03:51.887 UTC [45] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
```

```
ERROR: relation public.databasechangeloglock does not exist at character 22
```

Do you know why I am getting these errors?

My docker-compose.yml file is as follows (shown only partly).

```
version: "3.4"

services:
  sumo-db:
    image: postgres-sumo:1.4.0
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - DB_NAME_1=db1
      - DB_USER_1=user1
      - DB_PASS_1=pass1
      - DB_NAME_2=db2
      - DB_USER_2=user2
      - DB_PASS_2=pass2
    volumes:
      - sumo-db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data 
    restart: on-failure
    ports: 
      - 5432:5432
    networks: 
      - sumo
```

If you need further information feel free to ask me. As always thank you.

Inshaf

Comment: It would be helpful to see the content of your `docker-compose.yml` file. My guess is that the default Postgresql port in the official Docker image (`5432`) is mapped to port `5433` on the host using `ports` option in your YAML file.

Comment: Thanks for the response Hup. I have edited my original post to now include my docker-compose.yml file. Hope it helps you to identify any errors. Would love to hear you thoughts.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `postgres-sumo:1.4.0` image and I cannot tell where `5433` comes from (I also don't know where you executed the command; inside the container or on the host). For the second part of your question (URL on localhost), it is normal that you don't get any response. I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, it is not a web page.

Answer (score 0):

If the docker hypervisor is capturing connections to 5432 on the host and tunneling them into the container, netstat will attribute this to the hypervisor process, not to a PostgreSQL process.  netstat doesn't know who is on the other end of the tunnel, only its own end.  Now it could recognize 5432 as being a traditional PostgreSQL port and label it that way, but -n tells it not to.  Apparently you also have a 2nd instance of PostgreSQL, this one running directly on the host and on port 5433.

> When I type localhost:5432 in the url I don't see any page.

A URL is something you can type, not something you type other things into.  If you are putting that into the address bar of a web browser, that is not how you connect (successfully) to databases.

What is a vscode terminal?  Does it have anything to do with either PostgreSQL or docker? Does the message mean that this terminal committed those errors, or someone else committed those errors against it?

Comment: Thanks jjanes. I am running my docker-compoe.yml file on vscode in undetached mode so I can read any error messages on the terminal. That's where I got the errors mentioned in 3\. What do you mean by a 2nd instance of postgreSQL running directly on port 5432?? is it the second user, user2, and its respective database, db2?? And are you saying that it's not possible to see anything by typing localhost:5432 in the web address once my container is connected to port 5432??

Comment: The 2nd instance is running on 5433, not 5432.  It would not be for the 2nd user.  It might be completely unrelated to whatever you are doing, you just spotted it because you went looking for something with netstat.  If this is a shared machine, maybe someone else set it up.

Comment: If you want to test a connection to postgresql, you would generally do it with `psql -h localhost -p 5432`, not with a web browser.  Your attempt to point a web browser at 5432 is probably what led to the "LOG:  invalid length of startup packet".  PostgreSQL tried to interpret something from HTTP protocol as if it were a packet length from the PostgreSQL wire protocol, and found it wasn't valid as one.

Comment: When I tried to login using the command ```psql -h localhost -p 5432``` I got the following error ```inshaf@anubis:~$ psql -h localhost -p 5432
Password for user inshaf: 
psql: error: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "inshaf" ``` When I tried to login as root user I got the following error ```root@anubis:# psql -h localhost -p 5432
Password for user root: psql: error: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "root" ``` Why does it give me these errors??